# CSS Help required in Elementor and Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, woocommerce-bookings

Need Help, I need to make this calendar full width and bring this button below the calendar.
Here is the link of page
https://demowork.codersharjeel.com/product/product-1/

[Here is the image of how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKcaw.jpg)

Comment: Normally I wouldn't use !important.. but here you go `.woocommerce div.product .elementor-widget-container .elementor-add-to-cart form.cart {
    display: block !important;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the css solution you need. I use this with the elementor on many websites where the Woocommerce bookings plugin is used. Simple and fast hack. Just add this into your Elementor's woocommerce single product css.

```
.woocommerce div.product.elementor form.cart:not(.grouped_form):not(.variations_form) {
    display: block;
}
```